# Passing NSLocalizedString as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I have a class `MyOperation` that has a property `localizedTitle` that should return a localized title but the title is being set from outside:

```
@interface MyOperation

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title;

@property (readOnly) NSString *localizedTitle;

@end

@interface PTImageOperationSession() {
  NSString* _operationTitle;
}

@implementation MyOperation

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title

{
  [self retainSelf];
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    _operationTitle = title;
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSString *)localizedTitle {
  return _operationTitle;
}
@end


- (void)foo {
  MyOperation *operation = [[MyOperation alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MyLocalizedTitle", nil)]; // Good.

  NSSting *titleString = [self titleString]; // Can be different strings at runtime.
  MyOperation *operation1 = [[MyOperation alloc] initWithTitle: titleString]; // Bad because the title is not localized.
}
```

Question: Is it possible to insure that the class will always be initialised with localised title?  My responsibility as a class owner is to return a localized title, but it is being set from outside so I have no control on it. Would you tag it as a "design issue"?

Comment: What happens if you use: `_operationTitle = NSLocalizedString(title);`?

Comment: @RyanB as far as I know you cannot do so. You can only use string literals (e.g `@"..."`) with `NSlocalizedString`

Comment: Are you sure? I used to call the macro that way & it works without any problem.

Comment: @RyanB It should somehow be translated at compile time. `[[MyOperation alloc] initWithTitle:aTitleString]` and `aTitleString` may be resolved dynamically during runtime (e.g as an input from user).

Comment: If the user should pass a localized title to `initWithTitle:` then the method should be called `initWithLocalizedTitle:`. Otherwise I would expect `MyOperation` to localize the title.

Answer (score 0):

Passing variable to `NSLocalizedString` macro shouldn't be any problem, here is what I did for testing purpose:

Localizable.strings

```
"MyString"="My sample localized string";
```

And my TestClass

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSString *localizedTitle;

-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
@end

@implementation TestClass {
    NSString *_title;
}

-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title = NSLocalizedString(title, nil);
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)localizedTitle {
    return _title;
}
@end
```

Init my test class, then access its property

```
TestClass *myClass = [[TestClass alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyString"];
NSLog(@"%@", myClass.localizedTitle);
```

This is what I have in console:

```
2018-11-05 19:16:36.268393 TestApp[1471:352553] My sample localized string
```

**Update**

The macro:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
        [NSBundle.mainBundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

Is the shortcut to `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` function & according to the document:

> **Return Value**
>
> A localized version of the string designated by key in
> table tableName. This method returns the following when key is nil or
> not found in table:
>
> If key is nil and value is nil, returns an empty string.
>
> If key is nil and value is non-nil, returns value.
>
> If key is not found and value is nil or an empty string, returns key.
>
> If key is not found and value is non-nil and not empty, return value.

If you pass a non-existence key to the macro, you will receive the key itself. That's the designated behavior.

By the way, in common sense, you can't ask for a localized string if it isn't defined, right?

Comment: What if the title should be resolved at runtime (e.g. user input)?

Comment: Same result:
2018-11-05 19:55:37.712851 TestArray[1493:356908] My sample localized string
2018-11-05 19:55:37.713110 TestArray[1493:356908] My second sample localized string.

Check your title string, I guess it contains unexpected character which make the macro failed, hence your string get returned as-is.

Comment: Did you input "MyString"? And what if you input "Hello world" instead? I mean how do you know what to write in `Localizable.strings` if you don't know what the input will be?